# How to enable lazy loading on tabs in tabset in Angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I making `<tabset>` view to show the content in a page. Also I am using 
[Bootstrap's Tabs and Lazy Data Loading](https://github.com/xebia/angularjs-tabs-and-lazy-data-loading) so that the controller for a particular tab is initialized only when it is active. I am able to achieve lazy loading for the tabs.

```
<div id="panel" ng-controller="HomeController as hmctrl">
<tabset>
<tab  class="nav-item" id="tab_content" title="Tab1" template-url="app/components/tab1/tab1.html"></tab>
<tab  class="nav-item" id="tab_content" title="Tab2" template-url="app/components/tab2/tab2.html"></tab>
<tab  class="nav-item" id="tab_content" title="Tab3" template-url="app/components/tab3/tab3.html"></tab>
</tabset>
</div>
```

In my app.config I have only one route for the main page

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['bootstrap.tabset','ngRoute']);

app.config(
  function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'app/components/home/homeView.html'
    });
});
```

For every tab there is a separate controller assigned to them.
I would like to know how to assign routes to any particular tabs when created this way. So that I can navigate to them using `$location.path()` function.

I have created a plnkr for the same here 
[Plnkr for the above described scenario](https://plnkr.co/edit/9xGXzK)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using $stateProvider instead of $routeProvider in this case.
I have forked your plunker here- https://plnkr.co/edit/lL9JVRmuE8kQ5f0WhRDo?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['bootstrap.tabset','ngRoute','ui.router']);

app.config(
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/Home");

    $stateProvider
    .state('Home', {
      url: "/Home",
      templateUrl: "home.html"
    })
    .state('Home.Tab1', {
      url: "/Tab1",
      templateUrl: "tab1.html"
    })
    .state('Home.Tab2', {
      url: "/Tab2",
      templateUrl: "tab2.html"
    })
    .state('Home.Tab3', {
      url: "/Tab3",
      templateUrl: "tab3.html"
    });

});
```

Index.html - use ui-view instead of ng-view

```
<div class="ui-view"></div>
```

Home.html

```
<div id="panel" ng-controller="HomeController as hmctrl">
  <p>Home</p>
<tabset>
<tab  class="nav-item" id="tab_content" title="Tab1" ui-sref=".Tab1"></tab>
<tab  class="nav-item" id="tab_content" title="Tab2" ui-sref=".Tab2"></tab>
<tab  class="nav-item" id="tab_content" title="Tab3" ui-sref=".Tab3"></tab>
</tabset>

<div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

The url will be #/Home/Tab1 ,#/Home/Tab2, #/Home/Tab3 and you could force navigate to the state by:

```
 $state.go("Home.Tab2");//navigates to Tab2 of Home page
```

More about state providers here - https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

*Make sure you refer state provider script and inject this module in your app*

Answer (score 0):

You could add separate routes  to each tabs,

```
app.config(
  function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'app/components/home/homeView.html'
        controller:'HomeCtrl'
    });
   .when('/Tab1', {
        templateUrl: 'app/components/tab1/Tab1.html',
        controller:'Tab1Ctrl'
    });
})
```

Comment: I have added a plnkr code snippet please check that, you will know the situation I am trying to describe

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$routeParams` service. Take a look at the example code below.

Change your route configuration to include a tab identifier.

```
app.config(
  function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/:tabId', {
        templateUrl: 'app/components/home/homeView.html',
        controller:'HomeController'
    });
});
```

Then in your `HomeController` you can access the `$routeParams` service to get the current value of `tabId`.

```
app.controller('HomeController', function($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.activeTab = $routeParams.tabId;
});
```

Set the active property of tab accordingly.

```
<tab  active="{{activeTab == 1}}" class="nav-item" id="tab_content" title="Tab1" template-url="app/components/tab1/tab1.html" active="{{activeTab == 1}}"></tab>
<tab  active="{{activeTab == 2}}" class="nav-item" id="tab_content" title="Tab2" template-url="app/components/tab2/tab2.html"></tab>
<tab  active="{{activeTab == 3}}" class="nav-item" id="tab_content" title="Tab3" template-url="app/components/tab3/tab3.html"></tab>
```

Then you can call your tabs as `<baseurl>/1`, `<baseurl>/2`

Comment: This won't work for the scenario I am trying to explain, I have added a plunkr for the same I am trying to explain, every tab is having a separate controller with it.

Comment: I understand that and in your plunkr, you have already achieved that. I just provided you a way to bring a tab into focus based on the route. Could you please explain the problem you have with this solution more clearly?

Comment: All the tabs controllers are trigged together, and also the tab don't change if I change the url